# A regular expression to filter undesired usernames

Tags: regex, pcre

On a site I am working on I have a requirement that usernames not start with `<alpha><alpha>_`

So these should not be allowed:

- SU_Coolguy
- MR_Nobody
- my_Pony

But these should be ok:

- __SU_Coolguy
- MRS_Nobody
- YourPony

In the framework I am using, I am only able to validate against matching regular expression, not non-matching.  So far I have come up with this:

```
"/^([^A-Za-z0-9]{2}\_|[A-Za-z0-9]{3,27})/"
```

This works for most items, but fails on "__SU_Coolguy".

Any help on this regex would be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: If you need a PHP regex, it's not language agnostic.

Comment: @Peter Boughton: Actually, since what he wants is only the regex, it's not about php either. PHP uses PCRE, so retagged to `pcre regex`.

Comment: Fair enough, though I'd still leave `php` tag on, as a general rule, since there may be situations when a non-regex solution is better, so the `php` tag makes it more visible to people who can tell that.

Comment: @Peter Boughton: In this case, his (unknown) framework lets him only use regexes, so non-regex solution isn't possible with given data.

Comment: Good point - I mis-read that bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex would be `/^(?![a-zA-Z0-9]{2}_)/`. It means "start with *not* {two alphanumeric characters and an underscore}".

Comment: Was about to post same thing, well, except ignoring the `A-Z` and adding `i` flag on the end.

Comment: +1 and accepted for working to do exactly what I want without my extra crap on the end.

Comment: But this will not check if the rest of the string is alphanumeric or numbers.

Comment: bancer, that wasn't stated as a requirement. Shoving `\w+$` before the closing slash will do that though.

Answer (score 3):

This uses a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

`^(?![A-Za-z]{2}_)[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,27}$`

Lets break it down:

```
Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?![A-Za-z]{2}_)»
   Match a single character present in the list below «[A-Za-z]{2}»
      Exactly 2 times «{2}»
      A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
      A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
   Match the character “_” literally «_»
Match a single character present in the list below «[A-Za-z0-9_]{3,27}»
   Between 3 and 27 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{3,27}»
   A character in the range between “A” and “Z” «A-Z»
   A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
   A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
   The character “_” «_»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
```

Comment: Do you need to write "A character in the range between" every time? Makes it less readable, which is exactly the opposite of the intent.

Also, if you prefix comments with `#` then that stops the colour coding (as well as being valid regex syntax when the `x` tag is enabled).

Comment: Sorry, it is a generated thing from RegexBuddy (to lazy to type out an explanation myself)

Answer (score 1):

Just put in a negative assertion, like this:

```
/^([^A-Za-z0-9]{2}(?!\_)|[A-Za-z0-9]{3,27})/
                   ^^--Notice the assertion.
```

Here is a full test case:

```
<?php
$names = array('SU_Coolguy','MR_Nobody','my_Pony','__SU_Coolguy','MRS_Nobody','YourPony');

foreach($names as $name){
        echo "$name => ";
        if(preg_match('/^([^A-Za-z0-9]{2}(?!\_)|[A-Za-z0-9]{3,27})/',$name)) {
                echo 'ok';
        }else{
                echo 'fail';
        }
        echo "\n";
}
?>
```

which outputs this:

```
SU_Coolguy => fail
MR_Nobody => fail
my_Pony => fail
__SU_Coolguy => ok
MRS_Nobody => ok
YourPony => ok
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way in this case is just to break it into cases: the username either starts with a non-alpha, or an alpha and a non-alpha, or two alphas and non-underscore, so roughly like:

```
/^([^A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][^A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][^_])/
```